# Highlight cell only when hovering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table:

```
<table class="table table66 table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>age</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Alan</td>
        <td>11</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to highlight the cell I'm hovering, not the entire row. I've tried this with no success:

```
td.table66:hover {
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
.table66 td:hover {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

What you are doing in your sample is trying to select a `td` which also has the class `table66`, when it is your `table` which has the class.

Comment: You beat me to it. Haha!

Comment: yeah... that makes sense. This is embarrassing. Need more coffee to  wake up

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.table66 td:hover {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
```